# Change default data-loading-text for bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Since I'm building a Dutch website I would like to have the loading text on bootstrap buttons in Dutch as well. By default the text is `Loading...` can I change this default without having to add `data-loading-text="Bezig..."` in every button?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can 'initialize' your buttons with the data attribute when you load the page using standard jQuery:

```
$('button').data('loading-text', 'Bezig...');
```

OR, you can set the options for the button component like you would other components in Bootstrap:

```
$('button').button({loadingText: 'Bezig...'});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/mU3Nh/)

Comment: is there a way to overwrite the defaut prop of the plugin globally without using a selector ?

Answer (score 8):

I use this (after the bootstrap.min.js) to set it globally, it write the loadingText directly in the plugin prop, add this code in the jquery ready function :

```
$.fn.button.Constructor.DEFAULTS = {
    loadingText: '<i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> Chargement…'
}
```