# Change data-loading-text in Bootstrap globally

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to change text of `Button.DEFAULTS.loadingText` in `Bootstrap 3.2.0` globally at once so that I don't need it set by  `.button()` calling like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644085/104237):

```
$('button').data('loading-text', 'Bezig...');
// or
$('button').button({loadingText: 'Bezig...'});
```

This setting method above doesn't work for me because my "buttons" are generated dynamically. That's why I need the `loadingText` has to be set as global.

**Is there something like this?**

```
 $.fn.bootstrap.Button.DEFAULTS.loadingText = "Bezig...";
```

Comment: If you are hosting your own bootstrap files, you can just edit the js file and replace `loading...` with your own text.

Comment: @DavidG it's not a solution for me because I need to set it various times - it's a multilingual webpage so `loadingText` need to be set many times; many `bootstrap.js` versions isn't goal

Comment: In that case you could set every button manually when you create it: `<button data-loading-text="Blah...">`

Comment: @DavidG I know this "manual" solution but I'm looking for global setting for that. But thank you anyway.

Comment: I gave you a global solution, but you didn't want it, I'm confused! :)

Comment: @DavidG as long global as you can edit html code of buttons :)

Comment: Perhaps you could replace the string "loading..." in the Bootstrap file with a function call instead then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.button.Constructor.DEFAULTS.loadingText = 'Bezig...';
</script>
```

This need to be added after loading `bootstrap.js`.